# Encoding UTF-8 non-ASCII with Python's BeautifulSoup and SCV modules

Tags: python-2.7, csv, encoding, beautifulsoup, non-ascii-characters

This question evolves from my other question. I try to extract the name and place of the individual but some have non-ASCII characters. The script shows I can print the non-ASCII characters on my text editor (on Python IDLE but not on SublimeText 3 for some reason), but I can't save it into csv.

How do I save these entries along with original non-ASCII characters into a csv file?

```
# coding=utf-8
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from urllib import urlopen
import json
import csv

# John Stuart: https://familysearch.org/pal:/MM9.1.1/KH21-F11
# Napoléon Clément: https://familysearch.org/pal:/MM9.1.1/KHR6-D6D
Soup = bs(urlopen('https://familysearch.org/pal:/MM9.1.1/KHR6-D6D').read())

# Process into Json
rawJ = Soup.find_all('script')
J = str(rawJ[10])
J1 = J.split('var person = ')
J2 = J1[1].rsplit('var record =')
J3 = J2[0].rsplit(';', 1)

JsonText = J3[0].decode('utf-8')
s = json.loads(JsonText)

# Extract
placeHolder = []
name = s["personBestName"]
placeHolder.append(name)
print name

'''for i in s["facts"]:
    if i["type"] == "http://gedcomx.org/Census":
        event_place = i["place"]["fields"][0]["values"][0]["text"]
        placeHolder.append(event_place)'''

# Write into csv
with open("FamilySearchDataV2.csv", "ab") as f:
    writeFile = csv.writer(f)
    writeFile.writerow(placeHolder)
```